# AWS EC2 : Ubuntu Webserver - Process out of memory when running npm install

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been running an instance on AWS EC2 (Ubuntu Webserver) just fine for last couple of weeks. Recently, I tried to update my application and thus tried to install all `npm packages` again and restart my application.

However, I am running into out of memory problem whenever I run `npm install`

I have killed all `screen` process and also tried `killall node`

Is there any command I can use to free up some memory space for my EC2 instance?

Following is the error I am receiving when running `npm install`

[image]

I am using 2 disk volumes for my ES2 instances (8GB each). The first disk space holds the OS and second one holds my actual application.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't say what type of instance you're using, but I have seen this on occasion on t2.nano and t2.micro instances.

If that is the case, you have two options:  you can move to a larger instance type, or you can add virtual memory by configuring swap space.  If the application runs fine, and you only see this when running npm, then adding swap might fix the issue. The t2 family doesn't have instance storage, so you're have to add swap on one of your EBS volumes (if you have space) or on an additional volume.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, my application runs fine. I guess I will try to add swap or if I can't get it to work, I will upgrade to t2.normal, run npm install and switch back to t2.micro

Comment: I created a swap on my t2.micro and it worked perfectly. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: You save my day !!! 
Problem: Webpack need lot of memory to proceed and T2.micro only have 1 GB.
Solution: Attach the volume as a swap (https://dev.to/hardiksondagar/how-to-use-aws-ebs-volume-as-a-swap-memory-5d15)